# SQL Stored procedure in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

i am new to sql queries.

Kindly can anyone guide me where to start learning using storedprocedure in php and mysql ?

please help me with this eg:

I have 1 table Bill:

columns as: Title | Qty | Price | Total

in frontend i ask user for:
Title | Qty | Price

when user save the form, i want database to show:

Title | Qty | Price | Total

Here, i want to use Stored procedure to be executed on Total with the following:

Qty * Price

So, i want everything user add a new bill the total is calculated using stored procedure, and store total in db for that bill and show it in frontend.

Help with a eg. would be great and thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many ways to do this task. but I'll show you one:

```
//store the variable
$title = $_POST['Title'];
$qty = $_POST['Qty'];
$price = $_POST['Price'];

//connect to database
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'rootpassword';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

//sql syntax
$sql = 'INSERT INTO Bill (Title,Qty,Price,Total) VALUES ( ".$title.", ".$qty.", ".$price.", ".$qty * $price." )';

//select tabel
mysql_select_db('your_table_name');

//insert into tabel
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
   die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Yes, i know this one. i am just curious to learn about stored procedure method. without touching that in coding.. hope you understand :)

Comment: Leave it i got it i guess.. Thank you anyways.